# load xml into a database(variable scope)

Tags: c#, xml, database

I have a programming problem I can load a database(access) with xml successfully, when I turn it into a function it(tabelName) does not exist in the current context. How to reference it properly? I will have multiple tabels in the database containing information.

```
 private void loadDatbase(String fileName, String tabelName)
    {
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    string ConnString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\set.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
                    using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
                    {

                        SetCon.Text = "In try";
                        Conn.Open();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.ReadXml(@"c:\\temp\\"+fileName+".xml");
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
                        dtCSV = ds.Tables[0];
                        cmd.Connection = Conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        for (int row = 0; row <= dtCSV.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            if (dtCSV.Columns.Count > 1)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Property", (dtCSV.Rows[row][0])));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Pvalue", (dtCSV.Rows[row][1])));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Pdefault", (dtCSV.Rows[row][2])));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PType", (dtCSV.Rows[row][3])));

                                //cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO  table1 " (Property, Pvalue, Pdefault, PType) VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?)");
                                //The above works no wories however the string below does not tableName does not exist in the current context
                                cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO  "+tableName+" (Property, Pvalue, Pdefault, PType) VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?)");
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n Error " + ex + "" +
                        "\n"; ;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method parameter name is called `tabelName`, BUT you are using the variable `tableName` -- notice the spelling. Change your method:
`private void loadDatbase(String fileName, String tableName)`